# Flutter cannot focus on TextField in Stack Inside of Visible Overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Stack that contains (among other things) a TextField. This TextField is within the Stack's overflow which is making it so that I cannot give focus to this TextField.

I have something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: expanded ? 10 : 50),
        color: AppColors.LIGHT_BLUE,
        child: Stack(overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: <Widget>[
          _searchField(),
          ExpansionPanelList(
              expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
                setState(() {
                  expanded = !expanded;
                });
              },
              children: <ExpansionPanel>[
                ...
              ])
        ]));
  }

 Widget _searchField() {
    if (!expanded) {
      return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, 50),
          child: IngredientSearchField(
              searchFilterController: widget.searchFilterController,
              hint: 'Search in List'));
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
```

The `IngredientSearchField` is a Widget that contains the TextField. I was initially using a `Positioned` to wrap this field, but came across this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19445 - one of the ideas in there was to use a Transform.translate instead, but that did not work either. Is a Stack not the right approach here?

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible complete source code to illustrate your problem  so that we can easily help you.